# table form is flickring in my page when dropdown changing in screen?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I designed the table like the below.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">Name</td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <span id="filterByApplication"><%= Html.DropDownList("filterByName", new SelectList(Model.Applications, "Id", "Name", Model.SelectedApplication.Name), "ALL", new { @class ="dropmenu" })%></span>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1">Role</td>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: left">
            <span id="filterByRole"><%= Html.DropDownList("filterByApplicationRole", new SelectList(Model.Roles, "Id", "Name", Model.SelectedRole.Name), "ALL", new { @class = "dropmenu" })%></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">ID</td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input id="id" type="text" value="" class="input" maxlength="8"/>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1">UserName</td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input id="userName" type="text" value="" placeholder="UserName"/>   
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td colspan="6">
             <input  id="btnsearch" type="button" value="Search" onclick="searchrequest()"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Whenever click on name dropdown roles are loading in another dropdown at that time total screen i.t table controls all are aligning dynamically(flickering).please tell me how to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all colspan attributes from your table, except last one. Change it to colspan="4" (instead of 6).

If you need to set column's width, you can use CSS styles. For example:

```
<tr>
    <td style="width: 10%">
        Id
    </td>
    <td style="width: 40%">
        ...
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%">
        Username
    </td>
    <td style="width: 40%">
        ...
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: hi ,username dropdown based on it's content  changeing it's width.when i am select firstdropwn based on second dropdown loading.based on content in second dropdown the width automatically increasing decreasing.how to fix width of second dropdown?